# Complete end to end tutorial C++ with MYSQL Server 5.5

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have spent hours looking for a complete end to end tutorial on how to do queries with MYSQL Server 5.5? This is within a Visual C++ console application using Visual Studio 2010 Express. Has anyone ever seen an actual working tutorial for this set up? I am getting tonnes of errors when everything is linked with MYSQL Connector libraries. As said, I want to make my life simple by seeing a complete tutorial for this set up that actually works. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this not what you're looking for? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio.html

Comment: Instead of tutorial, look for a sample.

Comment: Updated docs link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-cpp-info.html